# AS3 Graphics Class: How does it work?

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, reverse-engineering

So I'm playing with a project where I want my class to be able to use the functionality of the Graphics class without needing to extend Sprite/Shape. My goal aside, I guess I'm confused as to how it works at all? It's methods don't seem to return anything, and since it's added as a child property of the Sprite/Shape classes , I can't seem to figure out what it's actually doing? It's also one of those classes that can't be instantiated.

At this point, I'm just plain curious.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

EDIT: I should provide more clear distinction of what I'm looking for as answer. I have read the documentation, but the documentation doesn't account for what AS3 is actually doing. I'm looking for educated guesses about the programatic relationship between Graphics and the the classes that use it.

Comment: If you are familiar with the canvas element in HTML5, the graphics property in a AS3 DisplayObject is kind of like a canvas, that you can draw to, using methods like drawRect() and such.

Comment: Instead of using inheritance to extend a Sprite, why not use composition and create a class member variable of type Sprite?

Answer (score 2):

This is what AS3 Reference says about the [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) class:

> The Graphics class contains a set of
>   methods that you can use to create a
>   vector shape. Display objects that
>   support drawing include Sprite and
>   Shape objects. Each of these classes
>   includes a graphics property that is a
>   Graphics object. The following are
>   among those helper functions provided
>   for ease of use: drawRect(),
>   drawRoundRect(), drawCircle(), and
>   drawEllipse().
>
> You cannot create a Graphics object
>   directly from ActionScript code. If
>   you call new Graphics(), an exception
>   is thrown.
>
> The Graphics class is final; it cannot
>   be subclassed.

Answering the first part of the question it's not possible to use the functionality of Graphics without using Sprite or Shape, because it cannot be instantiated or subclassed.

The methods of Graphics don't return anything but as a side effect of calling them vector shapes are drawn.